# Build postman collection using newman in Jenkins - No Result in Console

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

I am getting the Build: SUCCESS message on jenkins Console output, but not the detailed result like Iterations, executed vs failed etc.

i am using "newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/559ca99c65470714895de" as 'Execute Windows Batch Command'.

am i missing any plug-ins? please help?

Comment: Do you have `newman` installed globally?

Comment: collections from the url you provided is invalid

Comment: make sure you have installed `node` and then `newman` as part of your build process

Answer (score 0):

The collection link you have provided is not valid. 
Please make sure you have the following configurations before you run newman:

1. npm and node installed globally on jenkins. 
   If not refer to [Node Installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node)
2. newman installed globally on the jenkins. 
   If not `$ npm install -g newman`
3. please execute the command on shell (not on Windows Batch Command)
4. Mention the cli reporter and exitCode to let jenkins know incase of any falure in the command as `$ newman run <your collection goes here> -r cli --exitCode 1`

Recommended:  Create a node app and run your tests for advanced reporting and easy maintenance. Ex: [Sample Newman Node Application with Custom Reporters](https://github.com/ravivamsi/postmanframework)